# JTextField setText() method not updating Field

Tags: java, swing

I am attempting to update the `JTextField` text via the `setText()` method. However, when I attempt to do this, nothing appears to happen. I walked through with the debugger and determined this is indeed the case. `payField` is the `JTextField` instance I am using.

Here is the code:

```
public void payBill(double payment) {

    if((this.bill - payment) > 0)
        payField.setText("Bill not completely paid! You still owe " + "$" + (this.bill - payment));
    else {
        payField.setText("Thank you for choosing Team Turbo!");//Not updating!
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        payFrame.setVisible(false);
        System.exit(0);
    }


}
```

Visually, nothing happens after this method is called:

[image]

Any idea what is going on here? The entire GUI is ran inside a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` thread, just for clarification.

Comment: Perhaps try and validate the JTextField after the JTextField#setText() method: `payField.validate();`. Are you sure 1.5 seconds is enough time for a User to absorb the information displayed? A better idea instead might be to utilize a JOptionPane with a Confirm Dialog so that the User has time to acknowledge what is displayed and can select an button to dismiss it. You can add a custom JPanel to a JOptionPane Confirm Dialog if you don't like the default one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This...

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1500);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
payFrame.setVisible(false);
System.exit(0);
```

is highly suspect.

Swing is a single threaded API.  That is, any long running or blocking operation will prevent the UI from been updated.

In your case, I might recommend a Swing `Timer` instead, which will trigger a callback after a specified delay, without blocking the UI.

Start by taking a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: Well, I just removed the Thread.sleeps, but still the JTextField does not update. Any other ideas on whats up?

Comment: This could be an indication that the field you're interacting with and the field that's on the screen aren't the same, but since there's a `System.exit(0);` statement and I don't know what `payFrame.setVisible(false);` is doing, it's all just guess work